# How to deal with an awkward situation at work

Tags: work-environment

Not sure if this should be posted at the Workplace, but this question (for me) is more about interpersonal skills.

My colleague and I dated for some time, then we stopped doing so later on (she was the one who adduced that we should stop doing so). I respect that decision.

Then after some time, she got promoted (we're on the same team).

Our interaction became awkward and she would often criticise my work standards (I think her criticisms are mainly based on her observation; I never shared with her how I deal with things at work, it just comes to her through shared emails and perhaps the opinion of other people). I am also struggling as to why she criticises me, considering that I received recognition for the work that I've been doing.

I'm not sure if I provided enough context, but that's the summary in general.

We still interact but I know that it's just for the purpose of showing professionalism. I noticed that she tries her best to avoid having an interaction and I try to avoid having interaction as well (considering that she gives her utmost effort). However, whenever I speak up about work-related matters in team meetings, she usually reject my ideas; and I don't understand why (my ideas are relevant to the mission, vision and goals of the company).

Note that our dates were friendly rather than romantic.

I would like to know what are the things that I should do to deal with the situation I am in.

Comment: You say she was promoted: is she now your superior? Is she actually commenting having observed your work, or merely repeating what others have said? Have you asked (possibly outside the meeting) why your ideas are rejected?

Comment: For cultural background: which country?

Comment: Are you asking "How to deal with an ex-girlfriend, which now is my superior, criticizing my work?" If yes, you should update your title.

Comment: That's why dating a colleague is frowned upon by some companies' rules.

Comment: What is your exact goal? What options do you have to reach it?

Comment: You've given us your interpretation of what she has said, not actually what she said. Whilst this may seem to make no difference to you you aren't an objective observer. It could be that we read examples of what she said and it doesn't sound quite so clear that she is criticising beyond her job role but, due to your involvement, you perhaps jump to conclusions. (Not saying it is the case, only that it helps if you provide as direct examples as you can without compromising your anonymity).

Comment: What do you mean by "our dates were friendly rather than romantic"? (Are you sure she would say the same? I could see that making sense if the relationship was only a few casual dates, but not as likely if we had been dating "for some time".)

Comment: have you talked to her about it ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been in a similar situation and here's a few tips - though your culture will have the biggest impact on the final answer.  This answer assumes you're in a Western culture, like the US, Canada, some places in Europe.  In general, your question is part of why people say *don't dip your pen in the company ink*.

1. Be sure that she's being unfair before doing anything else.  She may be giving you good feedback - even overly critical feedback can still be insightful in some situations, as the inverse - sucking up to someone - doesn't really stimulate personal or professional growth.  Sometimes we feel someone is being unfair to us because we used to date, when in reality, our expectations are misaligned.  This may not be the case, but be sure it is.  If she's being critical, is there any truth to it?  At worst, she's being unfair; at best, you get a chance to grow from truly brutal feedback.
2. In general, if you are performing highly and others at work notice this, but she doesn't, this will reflect more on her than you.  In other words, she's taking a big risk here and if this is a pattern others notice, this gives you a chance to dispute some of the criticism, if that's what you choose to do.  You may also use this as an opportunity to switch teams or something else.
3. You may be in a situation where you can switch teams.  If you can do so, I would recommend it.  If not, use this opportunity as a growth opportunity and realize that you'll have to go the extra mile.  Build references inside the company outside of her to position yourself to be able to move to a new company, if the situation calls for that.

This situation sucks, but you are growing as a person.  One thing you're learning is never behave this way if a relationship doesn't go your way.  Vindictive behavior ultimately confirms why a person may have chosen to end a relationship, so if she's being extremely unfair to you, this reflects poorly on her.  You have a chance to shine here, even if there will be some awkwardness.